# Eclipse/Ant customizing android build multi apps

Tags: java, android, eclipse, ant

I would like an Android build system procedure, command line or Eclipse, to generate several .apk files from a single source codebase.

Comment: There is a similar topic already. This [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507784/multiple-android-application-package-apk-files-from-single-source-code) should help you.

Comment: I saw that already but i couldn't help me. I need something more automatic and not just for two apps but 7 apps

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Write a custom build script with various targets for each of your projects.

```
<target name="all" depends="project_1, project_2, project_3">
...

<target name="projetc_1">
<!-- build project 1 -->
...

<target name="projetc_2">
<!-- build project 2 -->
...
```

Take a look at this [Ant tutorial](http://ant.apache.org/manual/tutorial-writing-tasks.html) if you don't know where to start, and/or take a look at IDE's generated Ant scripts.