# Using the same android app as a base for a new one

Tags: java, android, eclipse

I have two android application projects in my workspace, Testobject and MyAndroidApplication.

I would like to use one of them, Testobject, as a base for the new one. For that purpose, I have setting up Testobject as a library (Properties - Android - checked Checkbox Is Library). In MyAndroidApplication I have add the lib Testobject (Properties - Android - Add...).

Now I can use all classes and ressources from Testobject:

[reference library](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9283040/eclipse-android-project-how-to-reference-library-within-workspace)

I have used an XML from Testobject and changed for example the ImageView.

```
/** called when the activity is first created */
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    ImageView stImageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageview_ov_remote);
    stImageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.car_launcher);
}
```

While clicking the ImageView, a new activity get started.

```
   Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestKlasse1.class);
   startActivity(intent);
```

The started activity is in the project Testobject.

How can I change a TextView from TestKlasse1 in the project MyAndroidApplication?

```
    //cutout from Testklasse1 in Testobject

    TextView testString;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_testklasse_eins);

    testString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testKlasse1TextView);

    }
```

I won't change the content in TestKlasse1, because I want to use this class for different apps. For example for a supermarket app or an automobile manufacturer app. I don't want only to change the ic_launcher. [Multiple Applications with different names](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19006793/multiple-applications-with-different-names-for-the-same-code-base)

How can I change for example the TextView, though the class is in another project?

Answer (score 0):

Via the Intent you can send parameters to the activity.

```
 Intent intent = new Intent(this, TestKlasse1.class);
 intent.putExtra("MY_STRING", "New Content");
 startActivity(intent);
```

And in your activity you get the contents (in `onStart`) by:

```
 String myString = getIntent().getStringExtra("MY_STRING");
```

Or you can add the string to a strings.xml resource file in the project, then you can override the value in the application project by using the same name.

Comment: I've tried this:  `...intent.putExtra("test", "hello cookie!");...`  But the text in the TextView didn't changed.   `String test = "hallo"; ...testString = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.testKlasse1TextView);  testString.setText(test);`

Comment: Call the setText with a hardcoded string, to see what's happening.