# Android choosing assets while building a apk

Tags: android, ant, build, apk

I have developed a application which is distributed to different clients. The problem is that only the images and other resources that I use are different. What I'm currently doing is, that I replace the resources(images and text) specific to the client and build the apk.

Is there a way that I can store all Resources separately for each client and create a build script or something, so that I can choose the resources specific for the client I'm generating the apk during the build process?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Multiple Android Application Package .apk files from single source code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7507784/multiple-android-application-package-apk-files-from-single-source-code)

Comment: Since those different APKs would require different package names, my suggestion is to place the bulk of your app into a library project and keep the client-specific apps/resource bundles as separate projects. This will be easier once gradle "flavors" are actually working.

Comment: 323go - I haven't create any library project. can u guide me with an example ?

Comment: Google can help you: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidLibraryProjects/article.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with such a script:

```
#!/bin/bash

ant clean

CUSTOMER_DIR="./default-customer"
if [[ -e ${CUSTOMER} ]]; then
  CUSTOMER_DIR="./${CUSTOMER}"
fi

rm -R ./res/drawables/
mkdir ./res/drawables/

cp ${CUSTOMER_DIR}/drawables/* ./res/drawables/

ant release
```

If you run it like this:

```
./build.sh
```

the drawables from `default-customer/drawables/` directory will be copied to `res/drawables`.

If you run it like this:

```
CUSTOMER=client1 ./build.sh
```

the drawables from `client1/drawables/` directory will be placed in `res/drawables`.

Comment: can the client1/drawables/ be stored any where on the system?

Comment: In general - yes. You can modify the path of `CUSTOMER_DIR="./${CUSTOMER}"` and point it to the place you prefer. You can as well create a mapping of paths per client. I just showed you the concept of doing this.